# How to have a link inside a Facebook Feed dialog's description using FB.ui?

Tags: facebook, hyperlink, dialog, facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

I can't seem to embed a link into the description part of FB.ui. I tried the obvious of inserting  tags but that didn't work.

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'Los Angeles, CA, United States',
    caption: 'The current condition for Los Angeles is Fair.',
    description: 'Temperature is 58&deg;F.\nLook at details: <a href="www.google.com">here</a>',
    link: 'www.google.com',
}, function(response){});
```

Please help!

The result below is what I'm trying to produce:

[image]

Comment: You can’t put your own links into the description, it gets handled as pure text by Facebook. And why would one want to do that anyway, since there is a link already? Repeating the same link? Redundant. Using another link in the description? Confusing to the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The answer is to pass a JSON object into the `properties` parameter:

```
var p = {
    "Look at details": {
        "text": "here",
        "href": "http://www.google.com"
    }
};

FB.ui({
    method: 'feed',
    name: 'Los Angeles, CA, United States',
    caption: 'The current condition for Los Angeles is Fair.',
    description: 'Temperature is 58&deg;F.\nLook at details: <a href="www.google.com">here</a>',
    link: 'www.google.com',
    properties: p
}, function(response){});
```

Comment: properties attribute was deprecated https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog